# Check which app is currently open on device

Tags: python, adb, logcat, appium, python-appium

I can launch app through appium and use that driver to do UI interaction through Python. 
But I am trying to launch app through python script. e.g. facebook app.
Can I determine which app is currently open?
Or can I use appium to do UI interaction on currently open app?

I want to know which app is currently open or which url is launched either in playstore on in browser?
Can appium handle this or I need to use something else?
Or can I use adb to pull this info?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `driver.current_activity` method:

From manual:

> Retrieving the current running activity The property method
>   driver.current_activity returns the name of the current activity
>   running on the device.

```
activity = driver.current_activity
assertEquals('.ApiDemos', activity)
```